# ASP.NET Core HealthChecks reports false negative with RabbitMQ

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

Using this [Enterprise HealthChecks for ASP.NET Core Diagnostics Package](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks) I'm facing an issue where the HealtChecks tells me my endpoint is unhealthy where in fact everything is working.

The error message I'm getting now (after updating the Nuget package to 5.5.2) is

```
[2019-07-17 11:25:16.147 +02:00 Error] 
[HealthChecks.UI.Core.HostedService.HealthCheckReportCollector] [] 
GetHealthReport threw an exception when trying to get report from 
http://url.domain/health configured with name {name}.

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the 
request. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport 
connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. --- 
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly 
closed by the remote host
```

And

```
[2019-07-17 11:25:16.482 +02:00 Error] 
[MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Transport.RabbitMqReceiveTransport] [] RabbitMQ 
Connect Failed: "Operation interrupted"
```

My Startup configuration:

```cs
public void Configure(
            IApplicationBuilder app,
            IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions
            {
                Predicate = check => true,
                ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
            }).UseHealthChecksUI(setup =>
               {
                   setup.ApiPath = "/healthchecks-api";
                   setup.UIPath = "/healthchecks-ui";
               });

            app.UseMvc();
            OnServiceConfiguration(services);
        }
```

```cs
public override void OnServiceConfiguration(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.AddConsumer<MailConsumer>();
                x.AddConsumer<MailFailedConsumer>();

                x.AddBus(provider => ConfigureBus(provider, 
                                                  rabbitMqConfigurations));
            });

    services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
}
```

```cs
private IBusControl ConfigureBus(
        IServiceProvider provider,
        RabbitMqSettings rabbitMqConfigurations) => 
             Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(
             cfg =>
             {
                 var host = cfg.Host(
                               rabbitMqConfigurations.Host,
                               "/",
                               hst => {
                                 hst.Username(rabbitMqConfigurations.Username);
                                 hst.Password(rabbitMqConfigurations.Password);
                               });

                               cfg.UseHealthCheck(provider);
                               cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, $"{typeof(MailSent).Namespace}.{typeof(MailSent).Name}", endpoint =>
                               {
                                   endpoint.Consumer<MailConsumer>(provider);
                               });

                               cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, $"{typeof(MailSentFailed).Namespace}.{typeof(MailSentFailed).Name}", endpoint =>
                               {
                                   endpoint.Consumer<MailFailedConsumer>(provider);
                               });
                            });
```

**When I don't use the consumers the HealthCheck is OK**. So there is a problem with the endpoints, but what?

Comment: Do you have an output of your service health endpoint?

Comment: You mean the output on the UI/Api? It has two outputs: 1. Mastransit-bus: `"MassTransit bus is not ready: "` and 2. MassTransit endpoint: `Failed endpoints: rabbitmq://{domain}/{event_namspace},rabbitmq://{domain}/authenticationapi3777209016hbfvx_dotnet_bus_8zkyyyykyeffonh6bdmokeobfq?durable=false&autodelete=true"`

Comment: This might be due to a bug that was reported. https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/1485

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I'm not sure it is the same issue as I'm not recreating queues, it's right from the start of the service.

Comment: it's because of different names being reported

Comment: you might be getting errors when you try to start the bus, have you looked?

Comment: @ChrisPatterson everything is fine, the service can consume and produce events. The problem here is HealtCheck reporting a false negative.

Comment: check with 5.5.3 that includes the fix for the mismatched names.